# Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in empty()

Tags: php

I am getting following error why is this?

> **Fatal error:** Can't use method return value in write context

```
foreach ($transfer_nids as $nid) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
    $Result[] = array(
        'S_name' => empty($wrapper->field_s->value()->title) ? 'no data' : $wrapper->field_s->value()->title,
        'r_name' => empty($wrapper->title->value()) ? 'no data' : $wrapper->title->value(),
        'max' => empty($wrapper->field_max->value()) ?  'no data' : $wrapper->field_max->value(),
        );
  }

return ai_wrap_result($Result, 'Info');
}
```

Comment: post your complete function, but for the moment i think its suggests that `return ai_wrap_result($Result, 'Info');` is returning null

Comment: How are you calling this function, I guess you are checking if the response of this function is empty

Comment: @noobie-php: null? if it returns null will it show the same error?actually i am new to php ! can you tell me what i need to do

Answer (score 0):

In (older versions) of PHP (<5.5) you can't use `empty()` on the return of a function directly, for compiler reasons.

What you need to do instead is save the result in an intermediary variable and check if that is `empty()` instead, i.e.,

```
foreach ($transfer_nids as $nid) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);

    $rName = $wrapper->title->value();
    $max = $wrapper->field_max->value();
    $Result[] = array(
        'S_name' => empty($wrapper->field_s->value()->title) ? 'no data' : $wrapper->field_s->value()->title,
        'r_name' => empty($rName) ? 'no data' : $wrapper->title->value(),
        'max' => empty($max) ?  'no data' : $wrapper->field_max->value(),
    );
}
return ai_wrap_result($Result, 'Info');
```

Comment: The same thing you did wrong earlier; don't use `empty()` on the return of a function, but use an intermediary variable instead, like I did in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of PHP (at least 5.3, but not 5.6), you cannot access members of objects returned by a method:

$wrapper->field_s->value()->title

You must either upgrade your version of PHP, or use a temporary variable.